# Fixed width site zoomed in with no meta viewport?

Tags: html, meta-tags

I built a page for a client that was originally responsive but they wanted it switched to be a fixed width.

Currently the page doesn't have a meta viewport tag, but it is appearing zoomed in on my iphone 4. My understanding is that it should automatically zoom so the width of the content is visible (975px). I've also tried:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=975">
```

and that is not working either, the same thing happens.  Zoomed in to the upper left of the page.

I've cleared my cache and refreshed a number of times. I feel a little embarrassed because I imagine I'm missing something right in front of me, but I'm hoping a fresh set of eyes will yield a solution.

[Here is a link to the page](http://ronandlisa.com/changeyourhomechangeyourhealth/)

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 0):

Insert the `viewport` tag in the `<head />`, as follow:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Here is the [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag).